# Way to get the no of Imageview that is clicked

Tags: android, imageview

I have a lot of imageview . Lets say I have a 50 ImageViews . These will be in one screen . Horizontal and vertical scrolling will be available .

```
for(int j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
{
    imageView[i*5+j] = new  ImageView(this);
    imageView[i*5+j].setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
    imageView[i*5+j].setMaxHeight(80);
    imageView[i*5+j].setMinimumHeight(80);
    imageView[i*5+j].setMaxWidth(90);
    imageView[i*5+j].setMinimumWidth(90);
    tblRow.addView(imageView[i*5+j],j); 
    imageView[i*5+j].setOnClickListener(this);

 }
```

Suppose an user will click on imageview[25] . Is there any direct way to catch that imageview[25] is clicked ? Or I will have to iterate over all  imageview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageView[i*5+j].setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       someMethod((ImageView) v);
   }
});

private someMethod(ImageView currentView) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
imageView[i*5+j].setTag(new Integer(j));
```

and then in the OnClockListener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Integer i = (Integer)v.getTag();
}
```